# Adaptive grid to balance sample density

Tags: python, geopandas, grids-graticules, hexagonal-grid

I have been following this tutorial https://james-brennan.github.io/posts/fast_gridding_geopandas/ in order to create a grid on a geographical area and to assign labels to each point.

I was curious whether there is a known algorithm and implementation that can further split or merge this grid so that the overall sample density per grid box is balanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It exists and it's called `tesspy`: https://github.com/siavash-saki/tesspy !